# Storage and recall function of TI-82 lead to different results with complex numbers

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I use the calculator TI-82 STATS.

When I use the storage function of my calculator I get a different results by using the "storage-letter" or the recall (Rcl) function.

Here a reproducable example:

```
 I type: sqrt(1+i) [ENTER]
 calculator shows result: 1.189207115e^(22.5i)

 I type: [STO->][ALPHA][MATH][ENTER]
 calculator shows result: 1.189207115e^(22.5i)

 I type: 1/[ALPHA][MATH][ENTER] (on screen it shows as 1/A)
 calculator shows result: 0.8408964153e^(-22.5i)

 I type: 1/[2nd][STO->][ALPHA][MATH][ENTER][ENTER] (on screen it shows as 1/1.189207115e^(22.5i))
 calculator shows result: 0.8408964153e^(-150.844961i)
```

Obviously, the two angles are different, even though I used the same input.  Why is that?

Comment: very weird! it looks like there is eternally a bug in the way the Ti8[234] series handles polar coordinates in degrees! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658185/weird-stuff-happening-with-complex-numbers-on-a-ti-84